# How to parse time from string?

Tags: java, parsing, time, localtime

I'm trying to parse string (11:23) to LocalDateTime using scanner, but im getting exception:
**Text '11:23' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 11:23 of type java.time.format.Parsed**

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 String timeGivenByUserString;
 DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

  System.out.println("Type the time HH:mm");
        try {

            do {
                timeGivenByUserString = scanner.nextLine();
            } while (!timeGivenByUserString.matches("\\d{2}:\\d{2}"));
            LocalDateTime timeGivenByUser = LocalDateTime.parse(timeGivenByUserString, timeFormatter);
            System.out.println(timeGivenByUser.format(timeFormatter));

        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

i also created similar method and it works just fine:

```
    private static void askAboutDate() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String dateGivenByUserString;
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

        System.out.println("Type the date dd.MM.yyyy");
        try {

            do {
                dateGivenByUserString = scanner.nextLine();
            } while (!dateGivenByUserString.matches("\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4}"));
            LocalDate dateGivenByUser = LocalDate.parse(dateGivenByUserString, dateFormatter);
            System.out.println(dateGivenByUser.format(dateFormatter));

        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What would you return if you had to implement the method yourself, when parsing 11:23, and why? Remember that you're asking for a Local**Date**Time

Comment: I would return hours, minutes and default values for seconds, miliseconds etc. Added my timeFormatter. Also i tried with LocalTime but it just didnt work either

Comment: Please show the localtime code and the exception you get with it

Comment: Add the following line of code in your `catch` block: `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: I changed it to localTime and this time it worked. I think i made some typo earlier, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Like the others mentioned. LocalDateTime does not support standalone time values. For that you should look at either the LocalTime implementation from java.time or use a third party library like Joda-Time.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
Change LocalDateTime to LocalTime

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String timeGivenByUserString;
        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

        System.out.println("Type the time HH:mm");
        try {

            do {
                timeGivenByUserString = scanner.nextLine();
            } while (!timeGivenByUserString.matches("\\d{2}:\\d{2}"));
            LocalTime timeGivenByUser = LocalTime.parse(timeGivenByUserString, timeFormatter);
            System.out.println(timeGivenByUser.format(timeFormatter));

        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Probably correct. If you would explain why it helps, it would be great.

Comment: [edit] your answer and post the code that works.

Comment: @Abra I agree that we would like to see an edit, an improvement of the answer. I disagree that code is necessary in this case. The answer already precisely describes what change to the code in the question is necessary.

Comment: I added a working code anyway, maybe someone will find it usefull one day :)